# Upon load having all expansion panels in open state with Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have accordion that creates expansion panels using *ngFor. They are working fine except I am trying to have all the expansion panels expanded upon load. Currently the way it is only the last panel will show expanded rest stay closed

```
<md-accordion>
<md-expansion-panel [expanded]="true" multi="true" *ngFor="let n in notes">
  <md-expansion-panel-header>
     <md-expansion-panel-title>
       <h5>{{n.title}}</h5>
     </md-expansion-panel-title>
  </md-expansion-panel-header>
    <div *ngFor="let h of n.items>
      {{h.item}}
    </div>
</md-expansion-panel>
</md-accordion>
```

Please let me know how to fix this so when it is loaded all panels are in expanded state not just one.
Thanks

Comment: you want to expanded one on load then it will work like its should be working

Comment: No I want all to be expanded on load not just one. Currently it just expands one on load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `multi` directive on the `<md-accordion>` and not `<md-expansion-panel>`.

see [Expansion Panel docs](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatAccordion) for more details.